# Why am I getting a series of A’s in confirmation boxes in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-yosemite

I am running Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and it’s giving me these kind of prompt boxes for some reason. I haven’t been able to fix it. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Appears to be a font issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perform all of these tasks, in this order...

- Verify & if necessary Repair disk, using Disk Utility.
- Fix permissions, reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) (freeware)  - Maintenance tab/Permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.
- Apply *(or **reapply** if already up to date)* 10.10.5 using the [10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832), not the delta from App Store